# How to stop automatic refreshing?

Tags: applications, huawei, android-versions, multitasking, emui

If I'm seeing a video on YouTube app, a website in Chrome, Firefox or checking some thread in Stack Exchange app and I minimize the app to open another app or go to home, then I return to previous app happens that automatically is refreshing the app (Youtube, Chrome, Stack Exchange or any other).

For example, if I'm seeing a video for 5 minutes, go to another app and then return to YouTube, automatically loads the same video but from the beginning, not in minute I stopped it.

The phone where this undesired refreshing happens is Huawei and has Android 9 and EMUI 9.1.0.

Another phone with Android 7.1 that is not Huawei and doesn't have EMUI, for example, doesn't make this kind of refreshing.

Is there a configuration option to stop this refreshing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Most likely this is not a feature but a limitation of Android. Apps in background are automatically closed when your system runs out of RAM (or because of other things the manufacturer has added). When you later go back to the app it tries to restore the state it had before, but depending of the app and the techniques used some states (e.g. of an opened web site) can't be fully restored. Therefore your video is reset to the beginning.

Comment: Thanks for answer. So it seems not to do for this issue?

Comment: The only "solution" I see is to complain at Google and the other apps that they do not store the current state when closed by the OS in background respectively does not restore it appropriately.  However some manufacturers (especially Huawei) are known for closing background apps very aggressiv. Therefore in some cases the app my be not the problem but the system which does not give the app enough time to save the state before closing/killing them. Which case in your case is the problem can not be determined without getting directly "in touch" with the device.

Comment: Thank you Robert for.your suggestions.